# How to login to Windows using PIN code programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, pinvoke, pin-code

In Windows 8 a new authentication method for non-domain users has been introduced: using PIN set in Control Panel.

Currently our application supports Windows logon by pre-saved password using `LogonUserW()` and now requires support of PIN as well.

How can we achieve that from .NET application, directly or by P/Invoke?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Desktop.

Comment: Do you know anything about the `ICredentialProvider` interface family? How comfortable are you with `COM`?

Comment: @JerKimball: Please share solution of any kind, if I'm not familiar  with a topic, some of my teammates will be for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So all that stuff is governed by the `ICredentialProvider` hive of interfaces - for Windows 8, they added an extension in `ICredentialProvider2`, mainly to tie credential providers to individual user accounts.

I'm no expert here, but I did dig up some references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776042(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776029(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706912(v=vs.85).aspx

My gut says you could probably create a slim wrapper for the COM interfaces (probably the `ICredentialProviderProvider` and `ICredentialProvider` interfaces), and invoke them that way...but I'm mostly guessing here.