# How to validate user login and PIN

Tags: winapi

Windows 10/11 provides login to the system with user Login/PIN instead of a password. Is there any winapi way to validate the pair Login/PIN?

Comment: what sense do this ? nobody validate pin. user password is stored in file encrypted by pin. pin provider use pin for decrypt password and pass to system user name and password. pin used only internally

Comment: Google Chrome used this when you tried to view passwords if it is enabled for login using a PIN. And I think if it is enabled for login then we should to use it too for validating in our software.

Comment: This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697908/), but never got a good reply. This article *might* be helpful to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport-login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the **authentication API** in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/authentication-functions), which describes several authentication [sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/about-authentication) (**[Credentials Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credentials-management)**, LSA Authentication, Network Provider API, Smart Card Authentication, SSPI, Winlogon and Credential Providers), and here is an [introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs) to using Windows Authentication in C#.